# C# wpf web control

Tags: c#, wpf, web

is any way to open a web browser(visible?) in specific browser and do action like clic button, search etc. i try

```
WebBrowser web = new WebBrowser();
web.Navigate(new Uri("https://www.google.com/"));
```

but i didnt see it. I too know i can do something like that

```
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("chrome.exe","http://www.google.com");
```

but how then make action there control it? Or the only way is open browse in wpf and show it on some king of window.

Comment: Did you add your WebBrowser to a container being displayed in the application? It's better to make the webbrowser in xaml if you're going to be using wpf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best place to actually start learning how to utilize the different Class Controls at our disposal from the .NET environment is reading their documentation!

[WebBrowserClass](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.webbrowser(v=vs.110).aspx)

They show a relative simple example of how to achieve what you want, with the creation of the webbrowser in XAML. In this XAML, they define a TextBox so you can introduce your absolute path, but also a button to perform the search when you click on it.

```
<Grid x:Name="MainGrid">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Center">
            <TextBox x:Name="addressTextBox" Width="200" />
            <Button Click="Button_Click">Go</Button>
        </StackPanel>
    <WebBrowser Grid.Row="1" x:Name="myWebBrowser" />
</Grid>
```

I changed the XAML part a bit, so you don't have your WebBrowser with limited Height and instead have it occupied most of the screen real estate.

PS. In all honesty i cannot pinpoint why your code-behind implementation on the WebBrowser is not working though.

Comment: One more question how can i get source of page into string? Like : 1- open a page 2- get source into string 3- display it in textblock or anything like label etc

Comment: My the source, you mean it's uri, right? 
With this line : myWebBrowser.Source.ToString(),  but unless your page has fully rendered, this property will be set to null, which will be a problem.

Comment: ok i made it using _LoadCompleted, but Source is giving me source link, how can i get source of page?

Comment: OK i done it with WebClient :) for anyone string html = new System.Net.WebClient().DownloadString(web.Source.ToString());